# What does Allen Hatcher mean by "tack $F$ onto $f$"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I find it hard to understand part of Hatcher's proof of exactness of the homotopy group sequence on [this page](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf#page=353#).

[image]

In the fourth line from the bottom, he says "We can tack F onto f", but I don't quite understand this, could you please explain this in a more formal language to me?

Comment: It is depicted by the supplied image.

Comment: @Hurkyl I do notice the picture, but I don't know what is the preimage of $f$.